# Is the EXACT same creation repeated in every Kalpa?

Tags: creation, kalpa

It is said that Brahma creates the world from his past impression. 
Does that mean everything is repeated again? Will I be asking his same question again in the next Kalpa?

Comment: Not exactly same, they may vary.. that's how the Kalpa Bheda comes in the picture...

Comment: Nature has no shortage of creativity so nothing to be repeated